# Selenium IDE Error-"table view is not available with this format" with Firefox 55.0.3 V(64-bit)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Selenium IDE gives error `"table view is not available with this format"` when launched with the new version of `FireFox 55.0.3 (64-bit).`

[image]

Comment: You have to use Firefox below 55, After firefox 54 IDE is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. From `Firefox version-55` onwards, Selenium IDE will no longer available to work.

Refer the latest update on [seleniumhq.](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the IDE only works with Firefox 54 and previous.

So the solution is to **downgrade to Firefox 54**. But instead of downgrading to Firefox 54, better [use Firefox PORTABLE 54.0.1.](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/portableapps/FirefoxPortable_54.0.1_English.paf.exe) To keep yourself secure, install Firefox 54 portable just for automated testing with the Selenium IDE and install the portable version of Firefox in a separate directory from your main Firefox. This way you can keep auto-updates on for your regular Firefox. This makes sure you are safe when browsing the web.

And once you have done this, there is another issue to overcome: For some reason [the IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) is marked as compatible with Firefox up to **34** only - even so it works just fine in Firefox **54**. So the Mozilla addon website prevents the install for now good reason :-(

Solution for this issue:

- Download the latest version of the XPI from a 3rd party website, for example from https://a9t9.com/howto/getseleniumide  (this is safe, as the XPI is signed)
- Drag the XPI on the Firefox 54 window - done!

Or try the new chrome-based [selenium ide](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kantu-browser-automation/gcbalfbdmfieckjlnblleoemohcganoc?hl=en) and give the authors some feedback.